# rake assets:precompile fails on windows machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, precompiler

I have a similar problem as reported many times, e.g. here: [rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production not working as required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778784/rake-assetsprecompile-rails-env-production-not-working-as-required/22779369)

My setup is as follows:

```
-- rails 5.1
-- any application (e.g. an empty one, just generated the app, bundle, rake assets:precompile)
-- error:
```

> c:\RailsApps\asset_pipeline_test>bundle exec rake assets:precompile
>   I, [2018-05-08T01:26:06.195454 #7876]  INFO -- : Writing c:/RailsApps/asset_pipeline_test/public/assets/application-a51a53658dfaa975cb4363f51d14bccf24d66c3d90c2186bf834c157151c4bd1.js
>   rake aborted!
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass
>   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

The same error occours for different apps.

The difference to other reported issues:

```
-- I am using two similar w7pro machines
-- on one machine rake assets:precompile is working
-- on the other machine it's failing
```

I put a 1:1 copy of the app and the Ruby/Rails installation folder from the working machine to the one failing.

I checked any kind of environmental variables and found no difference.

I guess there is a difference between the machines outside the app and Ruby setup.

Question: what difference could that be? Both machines are originally set up by identical OS images (by my company's IT), but they are not fresh of course

Uli

Answer (score 1):

Check the **ruby version** of system's current user

```
rvm list
```

Make sure the same is taken during bundle. If it takes someother version install ruby for the user properly.

Also **do bundle** in a better way

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

bundle's ruby version **should match** with current system users' ruby version. *bundle* could be found at

```
/usr/bin/
```

or

```
/usr/local/
```