# Don't know how to build task 'bundle' - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to precompile my assets:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and getting the following error:

> Don't know how to build task 'bundle' (See the list of available tasks with "rake --tasks")

After `--trace`:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
yarn install v1.17.3
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.04s.
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'bundle' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `invoke_task'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/Users/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
```

How to fix this problem? I tried to update my gems, re-installed everything, added `gem 'rake'` and still getting the same error. Thank you very much for your help.

Rails version: `~> 5.1.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up your commands so that you are attempting to call two commands as one.

It appears, you are actually trying to call only this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

With the command you have used originally, you are trying to call the rake tasks named `assets:precompile`, `bundle`, `exec`, `rake` and again `assets:precompile`. Since you don't have a rake task named `bundle`, you got the error you quoted.

Comment: I used the command from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778784/rake-assetsprecompile-rails-env-production-not-working-as-required)